# MySQL Select columns that matches with my data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Im trying to make a query in MySQL to retrieve certain data of one of my tables.

```
+---------------+-------------------+------------+
|    friendA    |      friendB      | firstDate  |
+---------------+-------------------+------------+
| Peter         |      Susan        | 05/05/2010 |
| Soshi         |      Peter        | 05/05/2010 |
| Peter         |      Marie        | 05/05/2010 |
+---------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Im trying to get all friends of Peter and firstDate field without fields that match with Peter's name.

Example of what I want.

```
+---------------+-------------------+
|    friends    |      firstDate    | 
+---------------+-------------------+
| Susan         |    05/05/2010     |
| Soshi         |    05/05/2010     |
| Marie         |    05/05/2010     |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

How could I get that?

Comment: Either a case expression, or a UNION ALL.

Comment: Could you explain me that pls? If possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case expression to chose the non-Peter name:

```
select case when friendA <> 'Peter' then friendA else friendB end, firstDate
from tablename
where 'Peter' in (friendA, friendB)
```

Or do a `UNION ALL`:

```
select  friendA, firstDate
from tablename 
where friendB = 'Peter'
UNION ALL
select  friendB, firstDate
from tablename 
where friendA = 'Peter'
```

Comment: It works fine! Thank you so much ;) I'll mark it as correct in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08a67/1

```
SELECT
  IF(friendA='Peter',friendB, friendA) as friends,
  firstDate
FROM t1
WHERE 'Peter' in (friendA,friendB)
```